# Is there a way to have a Send Email button on an Activity?

Tags: email, activities

When an email comes in as an Activity and we view the Activity It would be nice to have a button on the ACtivity to reply to the person and it create a Send Email action for that user.

Has anyone done this with an extension?

Comment: Was thinking about this and wondering how much work it would be to tweak the Schedule Followup feature to include the Send Email activity. That way one could edit the incoming email change the status to completed or whatever and do a schedule followup of Send Email and type the response. When they save the activity civi will send the email response and record the activity.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that someone has written an extension to do this but if there isn't one in the extension directory (I presume that you've looked) then you have to assume that no-one has taken the time to publish it.

I suppose I could end the answer there, but here's a bit more thought on how you would develop it...

Since this is a fairly reasonable thing to expect to do, would be fairly easy to implement just adding a link to a URL of the format civicrm/activity/email/add?action=add&reset=1&cid=[CID]&selectedChild=activity&atype=[ATYPEID] and an addition that is unlikely to break anything, then it might make sense as an addition to core. (I'm not sure we've worked out exactly how to draw the line on how to add it / this one seems borderline).

Implementing as an extension would be a good first step.

Note: adding the text of the incoming email would be a little harder, and need a bit more thought, though there would be a fairly straight forward way to do that - it's not rocket science.

Comment: Only thing is,  this particular activity isn't just Incoming Email. I have webform accruing as my Contact us page and it creates a contract and activity of type Incoming Communication with status Needs Response. This is assigned to me and shows up on my dashboard.  So is need to be able to set the activity types that the Respond by email button showed up for.

Comment: oh! when you said "When an email comes in as an Activity", I thought you meant that the activity was an email :)

Comment: "need to be able to set the activity types that the Respond by email button showed up for" I don't think that'd be too difficult.